# Rewrite all paths for storybook build to deploy on github pages

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, storybook

My file structure is like in a [next.js][1] repo. So it's like:

```
| components  
|-- headline.tsx  
|-- headline.stories.tsx
| public  
|-- font  
|--|-- myfont.woff
```

The headline uses a specific font, which is imported there.

To start storybook I use `start-storybook -s ./public`. So all the files from the public folder are included in the dev-build.

In the next step I want to deploy all the stuff to a github page. So build the stufff `storybook-build` and deploy it `npx gh-pages -d storybook-static`.
Result: Storybook works and the Headline is there.
BUT the font is wrong. This is because the font is imported with an absolute path `/font/myfont.woff`. This leads to an github-pages url like this `https://blubber.github.io/font/myfont.woff` but it should be `https://blubber.github.io/MYPROJECT/font/myfont.woff`.

So I need a way to rewrite ALL paths in the project, but only if storybook wants to build the production stuff. Any ideas?

My ideas:

1. use `<base>`-tag in the `<head>` of storybook but this does only work with relative paths
2. add publicPath in main.js like `config.output = { publicPath: 'https://blubber.github.io/MYPROJECT/'}` => This will not rewrite paths within css

Can anyone help here?
[1]: https://github.com/vercel/next.js